# Could not load file or assembly 'app_code' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-6

This has been bothering me for a while now:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'app_code' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm using visual studio 2008 and IIS6 and for some reason I get this weird error.

Why is it trying to load 'app_code', and why does it fail?

Tried to resolve it/ find out more using the information in the exception

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

But that didn't help, neither did the information in the msdn article about the Assembly Binding Log Viewer: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)

Anyone can shine a light on this abomination? I'm guessing this is a newbie mistake but I have no idea where to look now. Could it be IIS 6.0 configuration issue? I am using Windows XP Professional Edition and Visual Studio 2008.

---

After getting the Assembly binding monitor up, it spews out something like:

```
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Projects\NNNNNN\src\Trunc\Web\web.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/d94fb3b9/d76068ec/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/d94fb3b9/d76068ec/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/NNNNNN/src/Trunc/Web/bin/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/NNNNNN/src/Trunc/Web/bin/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/d94fb3b9/d76068ec/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/d94fb3b9/d76068ec/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/NNNNNN/src/Trunc/Web/bin/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/NNNNNN/src/Trunc/Web/bin/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Comment: I forgot to mention we are using separate libraries for the code, rather than usnig the App_Code folder. The App_Code folder is empty in my project.

Comment: The solution also consists of a subsite which is built using MVC, so its a mixed asp.net regular forms and asp.net mvc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error was due to web.config was referencing the wrong package for a class. Clearing the mind over the weekend, and problems are solved easily.

Comment: Can you tell in detail about what assembly was referenced incorrectly??? I am facing the same problem. Need your help on this one...

Comment: Why you didn't tell us what exactly the assembly that was referenced incorrectly !! .. I think you can do it with no huge effort !

Answer (score 3):

If you use Visual Studio Performance Tools then it is possible that Visual Studio left a key in your web.config appsettings section.  It causes a 32 bit library to load, which won't work if your application is loading in 64 bit mode.

Check for the following and remove it:

```
<add key="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper.VsInstrLocation" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\vsinstr.exe"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a stab in the dark, but maybe there's a problem with your ASP.Net installation on your IIS.  Try opening a Visual Studio command prompt and running

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

This will reinstall ASP.Net into IIS.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However I have already tried reinstalling the ASP.NET like that, and it did not help. It would suck to have to reinstall the environment, since It would be interesting to find out whats actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me when I first tried to deploy a recently upgraded app (vs2008 to vs2010) using the "Publish..." option and didnt asked to delete the original content.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I try to make a publish.

Try to disable your antivirus.

This work for me!

Answer (score 0):

My application's target framework was .NetFramework 4. But I had selected .NET Version v2 as .NET CLR Version of application pool in IIS.
I've changed .NET CLR Version of application pool from v2 to v4 and worked for me.